# regex for getting rid of single space after comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this :

```
Anchor, Island, Super Over,  Power Play
```

I want this:

```
Anchor,Island,Super Over, Power Play
```

Power Play has two spce

Comment: Firstly, format your I/O. Second, input some code.

Comment: `str.replace(/,\s+/g, ',')`

Comment: `s = s.replace(/, /g, ',');`

Answer (score 1):

This would replace comma and a single space with comma.

```
> "Anchor, Island, Super Over,  Power Play".replace(/,\s/g, ",")
'Anchor,Island,Super Over, Power Play'
```

OR

This would replace one or more spaces after the comma with an empty string.

```
> "Anchor, Island, Super Over,  Power Play".replace(/,\s+/g, ",")
'Anchor,Island,Super Over,Power Play'
```